# Why is there no std::allocate_unique function in C++14?

Tags: c++, std, c++14

Why does `shared_ptr` have allocate_shared while `unique_ptr` does not have allocate_unique? 
 I would like to make a unique_ptr using my own allocator: do I have to allocate the buffer myself and then assign it to a unique_ptr? 
 This seems like an obvious idiom.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Why does `shared_ptr` have `allocate_shared` while `unique_ptr` does not have `allocate_unique`?

`shared_ptr` needs it so that it can allocate its internal shared state (the reference count and deleter), as well as the shared object, using the allocator. `unique_ptr` only manages the object; so there is no need to provide an allocator to the `unique_ptr` itself, and less need for an `allocate` function.

<sub>(There is also less need for `make_unique` for the same reason, which is probably why it didn't feature in C++11, but was added to C++14 by popular demand for the sake of consistency. Maybe the same demand will add `allocate_unique` to a future standard.)</sub>

> do I have to allocate the buffer myself and then assign it to a unique_ptr?

Yes. Or you could write your own `allocate_unique`; unlike `allocate_shared`, it's possible, and reasonably straightforward, to implement it separately from `unique_ptr` itself. (As mentioned in the comments, you'd have to make sure it used an appropriate deleter for the allocator; the default deleter would use `delete` and go horribly wrong).

> This seems like an obvious idiom.

Indeed. But so are many other idioms, and not everything can (or should) be standardised.

For a more official justification of the current lack of `allocate_unique`, see the [proposal for `make_unique`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3588.txt), specifically section 4 (Custom Deleters).

Comment: +1. The type erasure aspect mentioned in the proposal is most important IMHO, what type would `allocate_unique` return?

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Good point. Perhaps my claim that it's "reasonably straightforward" might change if I actually tried to do it.

Answer (score 28):

> do I have to allocate the buffer myself and then assign it to a unique_ptr?

Not just a buffer, a pointer to an object. But the object might need to be destroyed by the allocator, and the memory definitely needs to deallocated by the allocator, so you also need to pass the allocator the the `unique_ptr`. It doesn't know how to use an allocator, so you need to wrap it in a custom deleter, and that becomes part of the `unique_ptr`'s type.

I think a generic solution would look something like this:

```
#include <memory>

template<typename Alloc>
struct alloc_deleter
{
  alloc_deleter(const Alloc& a) : a(a) { }

  typedef typename std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::pointer pointer;

  void operator()(pointer p) const
  {
    Alloc aa(a);
    std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::destroy(aa, std::addressof(*p));
    std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::deallocate(aa, p, 1);
  }

private:
  Alloc a;
};

template<typename T, typename Alloc, typename... Args>
auto
allocate_unique(const Alloc& alloc, Args&&... args)
{
  using AT = std::allocator_traits<Alloc>;
  static_assert(std::is_same<typename AT::value_type, std::remove_cv_t<T>>{}(),
                "Allocator has the wrong value_type");

  Alloc a(alloc);
  auto p = AT::allocate(a, 1);
  try {
    AT::construct(a, std::addressof(*p), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    using D = alloc_deleter<Alloc>;
    return std::unique_ptr<T, D>(p, D(a));
  }
  catch (...)
  {
    AT::deallocate(a, p, 1);
    throw;
  }
}

int main()
{
  std::allocator<int> a;
  auto p = allocate_unique<int>(a, 0);
  return *p;
}
```

Comment: @LucDanton, I rolled back your edit, I chose to reject rather than rebind very explicitly. `allocate_shared` has to rebind anyway, so it doesn't matter, but here that's not true. If containers can require the correct value_type then so can my `allocate_unique` impl :-)

Comment: Thanks Jonathan.  I have been pondering my ACCU notes rather than coding much recently but I have used this code in three places without incident, so it tentatively gets the Hatcat seal of approval.

Comment: @hatcat, cool, glad it's working. Thanks for your lightning talk at ACCU, it reminded me how much I want to play Isolation.

Comment: +1 -- just wrote this exact same thing myself (down to the `main` code) to understand what the deal was with `D::pointer`. Thought I should post it, but here it already is :-) In my version I removed `T` from the template parameters and used `AT::value_type` instead, and I don't have a private member, but a base class instead.

Comment: I use a similar approach, just that in order to support polymorphic classes, I changed the validation to accept `std::is_same<>` or `std::is_base_of<>`. With this change I can create objects for derived classes while still using the allocator parametrised with the base class.

Comment: I have the impression that if the function is called `allocate_unique` then the function should `construct` at all, (and the deleter should `destroy` at all). With this same logic `allocate_shared` would be also a misnomer. This functions should be called different, even `make_unique`/`make_shared` with an extra first parameter (the allocator) should have been better.

Comment: Why do you need `std::addressof(*p)` here? Can we replace it with just `p`?

Comment: @Sergey no, you can't. The `construct` function takes an actual pointer, i.e .a `T*`, but an allocator's `pointer` type might be a "fancy pointer" i.e. a pointer-like class type. Dereferencing it and then using `addressof` gets a real pointer of type `T*`. Since C++20 you can use `std::to_address(p)` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. I was not obvious from documentation why it could be needed.

Comment: Thank you jonathan! I have trouble understanding however why you create another allocator object inside your operator()()? You capture by value already, why not use the allocator provided in the class member? Same in allocate_unique() function, the allocator is provided but you chose to reinstantiate a copy. Why is that?

Comment: @glades because `operator()` is const so cannot call non-const member functions on `a`. Similarly, `allocate_unique` takes a `const Alloc&` so cannot call `allocate` on it. In both cases you need a non-const copy of the allocator to call its non-const member functions.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Right! Seems like an oversight that allocator_traits::destroy and ::deallocate don't take the allocator by const ref..

Comment: @glades not an oversight. That would have made them incompatible with `std::allocator`