# Overloading new and delete, what's with new[] and delete[]?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

A very short question, but surprisingly I didn't find anything on the web:

I'm overloading `new` and `delete` for a class. Do I also need to overload `new[]` and `delete[]` or will they automatically "redirect" to the overloaded `new` and `delete`?

Comment: You could test this trivially...

Comment: You should probably do none of those things. The correct way to customize allocation is via allocators, and the correct way to have arrays is via the library (e.g. `std::vector`).

Comment: According to Scott Meyers in his Effective C++ book, "if you'd like to control memory allocation for arrays on a per-class basis, you need to implement operator new's array-specific cousin,operator new[]  [...]  If you decide to write operator new[], remember that all you're doing is allocating a chunk of raw memory — you can't do anything to the as-yet-nonexistent objects in the array. In fact, you can't even figure out how many objects will be in the array." However, regarding your specific question, I'm unsure now about what would happen if you overload new but don't overload new[]...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: You can test this trivially to some extent. But experience tells that there can be pitfalls behind such questions even if they work at a first glance.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: I now understand the usage of allocators with std containers, but how do I replace a plain `new MyObj()`with an allocator?

Comment: @Michael: Don't have a plain new! If you use unique pointers, you can write your own `allocate_unique`, or take the one [Jon Wakely implemented](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23132307). If you use shared pointers, they already support allocators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are talking about class-specific overloading, not replacing the global operators new and delete(which should be avoided unless really needed).

Anyway, to answer your question, No- they don't automatically redirect. You have to specifically overload operators that you need. new and new[] are two different operators.

Answer (score 1):

No it will not automatically do any forwarding. `operator new` and `operator new[]` do different things.