# using std::unique_ptr with allocators

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, allocator

I was trying my hand with allocators this time & felt that there were many chances of leaking the resources. So I thought what if I used `std::unique_ptr` to handle them. I tried my hand with a `std::vector`'s allocator. My code goes like this :-

```
// allocator
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

class X
{
    int x,ID;
    static int i;
    public:
        X()
        {
            cout<<"constructing ";
            ID=++i;
            cout<<"ID="<<ID<<'\n';
        }
        X(int a)
        {
            x=a;
            cout<<"constructing ";
            ID=++i;
            cout<<"ID="<<ID<<'\n';
        }
        void get()
        {
            cout<<"enter x: ";
            cin>>x;
        }
        void disp()
        {
            cout<<"x="<<x<<'\t';
        }
        ~X()
        {
            cout<<"destroying ID="<<ID<<'\n';
        }
};
int X:: i=0;

int main()
{
    ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    vector<X> v;
    auto alloc = v.get_allocator();
    unsigned int i=0;

    X *p(alloc.allocate(5));        
    for (i=0;i<5;++i)
    alloc.construct (&p[i], i+1);
    unique_ptr<X[]> ptr(p);

    cout<<"\nthe elements are:-\n";
    for (i=0;i<5;++i)
    {
        ptr[i].disp();
        cout << '\t' << (long long)alloc.address(ptr[i]) << '\n';
    }
    cout<<"\n";

    /*for (i=0;i<5;++i)
    alloc.destroy(&p[i]);
    deallocate(p,16)*/

    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately this code crashes showing `UB`. So what should I do ? How should I manipulate my code so as to make it suited for `std::unique_ptr` ?

Comment: i guess u wud need to write a separate `make_unique type function` & `custom deleter` in this case

Comment: @CppNITR could you explain it with a code ?

Comment: [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23132307).

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Comment: @black what do you want me to do

Comment: @KerrekSB couldn't it be simpler

Comment: Hey, you're the one who started it by saying the "a"-word. You got what you deserve :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB :P still....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
template<typename T>
std::unique_ptr<T[], std::function<void(T *)>> make_T(X *ptr, std::allocator<T> alloc, std::size_t size) {
    auto deleter = [](T *p, std::allocator<T> alloc, std::size_t size) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            alloc.destroy(&p[i]);
        }
        alloc.deallocate(p, sizeof(T) * size);
    };

    return {ptr, std::bind(deleter, std::placeholders::_1, alloc, size)};
}



int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    std::allocator<X> alloc = std::allocator<X>();

    X *p = alloc.allocate(5);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        alloc.construct(&p[i], i + 1);
    }

    auto ptr = make_T(p, alloc, 5);

    return 0;
}
```

Can also write one to construct the objects for you:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
std::unique_ptr<T[], std::function<void(T *)>> make_T_Construct(std::allocator<T> alloc, std::size_t size, Args... args) {

    X *ptr = alloc.allocate(size);

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        alloc.construct(&ptr[i], std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }


    auto deleter = [](T *p, std::allocator<T> alloc, std::size_t size) {
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            alloc.destroy(&p[i]);
        }
        alloc.deallocate(p, sizeof(T) * size);
    };

    return {ptr, std::bind(deleter, std::placeholders::_1, alloc, size)};
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    std::allocator<X> alloc = std::allocator<X>();

    auto ptr = make_T_Construct(alloc, 5, 100);

    return 0;
}
```

**Edit:** To do what you want (tracking allocations), you have to track the memory allocations yourself using a custom allocator..

```
template<typename T>
struct Allocator
{
    typedef T value_type;

    Allocator() noexcept {};

    template<typename U>
    Allocator(const Allocator<U>& other) throw() {};

    T* allocate(std::size_t n, const void* hint = 0)
    {
        T* memory = static_cast<T*>(::operator new(n * (sizeof(T) + sizeof(bool))));

        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < n * (sizeof(T) + sizeof(bool)); ++i)
        {
            *reinterpret_cast<bool*>(reinterpret_cast<char*>(memory) + sizeof(bool)) = false;
        }

        return memory;
    }

    void deallocate(T* ptr, std::size_t n)
    {
        ::operator delete(ptr);
    }

    void construct(T* p, const T& arg)
    {
        destroy(p);
        new(p) T(arg);
        *reinterpret_cast<bool*>(reinterpret_cast<char*>(p) + sizeof(bool)) = true;
    }

    template<class U, class... Args>
    void construct(U* p, Args&&... args)
    {
        destroy(p);
        ::new(p) U(std::forward<Args>(args)...);

        *reinterpret_cast<bool*>(reinterpret_cast<char*>(p) + sizeof(bool)) = true;
    }

    void destroy(T* p)
    {
        if (*reinterpret_cast<bool*>(reinterpret_cast<char*>(p) + sizeof(bool))) {
            p->~T();
            *reinterpret_cast<bool*>(reinterpret_cast<char*>(p) + sizeof(bool)) = false;
        }
    }

    template<class U>
    void destroy(U* p)
    {
        if (*reinterpret_cast<bool*>(reinterpret_cast<char*>(p) + sizeof(bool))) {
            p->~U();
            *reinterpret_cast<bool*>(reinterpret_cast<char*>(p) + sizeof(bool)) = false;
        }
    }
};

template <typename T, typename U>
inline bool operator == (const Allocator<T>&, const Allocator<U>&)
{
    return true;
}

template <typename T, typename U>
inline bool operator != (const Allocator<T>& a, const Allocator<U>& b)
{
    return !(a == b);
}
```

Comment: i appreciate ur efforts but this can't prevent memory leaks

Comment: @AnkitAcharya it would be better if you show your code which leaked

Comment: `cpp.sh/5wp6b` check this. `ID = 6` will leak here. I know it leaks because of the for loop statement but my point is that `unique_ptr` should take care of such erogenous construction as it always does

Comment: Wait.. so you're allocating a class into some memory. Overwriting the memory and expecting the class to automatically destruct.. I don't know if you understand how allocators work, but the class will NEVER destruct until you call destroy. That's not `std::unique_ptr` fault. It's your fault for intentionally leaking it. Allocators use `placement new` and you must delete it by calling the destructor explicitly (which is what the point of destroy is).  Your problems lie elsewhere.

Comment: got it @Brandon, then it means `unique_ptr` is apparently useless when it comes to `allocators` or is it ?

Comment: @AnkitAcharya it isn't.. http://cpp.sh/5c6u Just use a custom allocator that tracks memory allocations.. `std::unique_ptr` is doing it's job correctly. It's destroying your array, not the allocated objects within that array. It does NOT know that you allocated those objects using placement new. However, if you created an allocator that KNOWS this information, then `std::unique_ptr` will do what you want (it's actually the allocator that is doing the work since it does the allocations & destructions).

Comment: @Brandon i guess you should prefer `using` over `typedef` & `noexcept` over `throw()`