# Passing a unique pointer's pointer to a function that takes a double pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, unique-ptr

I have a function that effectively does this

```
void foo(Class** c)
{
    // memory checks and stuff
    (*c) = new Class();
    // more stuff
}
```

I cannot change this function. To call this function I have to do something like this.

```
Class* c = nullptr;
foo(&c);
if (c)
{
    // stuff
}
delete c;
```

I would very much prefer to use a `std::unique_ptr` rather than the raw pointer. However, I don't know how to get the address of the internal pointer. The listing below does not compile, obviously, because I'm trying to take the address of an rvalue.

```
std::unique_ptr<Class> c = nullptr;
foo(&(c.get()));
if (c)
{
    // stuff
}
```

I realize I could make the raw pointer as well as the unique pointer, call the function, then give the raw pointer to the unique pointer, but I would prefer to not. Is there a way to do what I want to do?

Comment: Whomever create that `foo` function should think about the `return` statement.

Comment: Passing it would spell possible memory leak. But you can used that function as part of allocation process. E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33845132/using-stdunique-ptr-with-allocators

Comment: Why not simply invert that: call the function, then create the `unique_ptr` from it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a wrapper around `foo`:

```
std::unique_ptr<Class> foo()
{
    Class* c = nullptr;
    foo(&c);
    return std::unique_ptr<Class>(c);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your hands are tied by the API of the function.

The best solution I personally see is to do what you said you'd rather not: create the unique_ptr after calling the function.

If you call this function a lot or if you have many functions like it I would create a wrapper function that creates locally the raw pointer and returns unique_ptr.